# Using tilde to get MAX value for int

Tags: c++, c, memory

I tryed to get MAX value for int, using tilde.But output is not what I have expected.
When I run this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main(){
    int a=0;
    a=~a;
    printf("\nMax value: %d",-a);
    printf("\nMax value: %d",INT_MAX);
    return 0;
}
```

I get output:

**Max value: 1**

**Max value: 2147483647**

I thought,(for exemple) if i have **0000** in RAM (i know that first bit shows is number pozitiv or negativ).After ~ **0000** => **1111** and after -(**1111**) => **0111** ,that I would get MAX value.

Comment: "using tilde" - if you want to get the max value for int, always use `INT_MAX`. Since you tagged this question C++, you could also use `numeric_limits<int>::max()` after `#include <limits>` (if you like being overly verbose, or if you need to switch the type.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a 32-bit two's complement system.  So - `a = 0` is straightforward.  `~a` is `0xffffffff`. In a 32-bit two's complement representation, `0xffffffff` is `-1`.   Basic algebra explains that `-(-1)` is `1`, so that's where your first printout comes from.  `INT_MAX` is `0x7fffffff`.

Your logical error is in this statement:  "-(**1111**) => **0111**", which is *not true*.  The arithmetic negation operation for a two's complement number is equivalent to `~x+1` - for your example:

```
~x + 1 = ~(0xffffffff) + 1
       = 0x00000000 + 1
       = 0x00000001
```

Comment: @DarkDust - no.  `abs(~0)` is `abs(0xffffffff)` or `abs(-1)` or `1`, the same as the OP's problem.

Comment: @Darkdust - No, there isn't an int that is abs(~0). It would be INT_MAX + 1.

Comment: @Bo, wrong again.  `abs(~0)` is `1`, at least given a reasonable implementation of `abs()`.

Comment: Always an interesting interview question. In Java, at least, Math.abs() is defined to return a -'ve answer if passed Integer.MIN_VALUE - since it can't return a +'ve answer.

Comment: @dty, that's true - the documentation for the standard C implementation of `abs()` says "The absolute value of the most negative integer remains negative." in the `BUGS` section.  Given the OP's program, `printf("%d", abs(a))` will also end up printing `1`.

Comment: @SauceMaster - no.  If `a` were `unsigned int`, the output would (probably) be exactly the same.  It would cause some undefined behaviour due to format string mismatches, though... there would need to be several changes to the program to make it behave properly when changing the type of `a`.

Comment: Why not use sizeof(int)*8 to determine what it is on your system.
Example: INT_MAX = 1 << (sizeof(int)*8) - 1;

Comment: @SinisterRainbow, your suggestion won'worst a reasonable answer on a system without 8-bit bytes, and causes undefined behaviour on those with 8-bit bytes.  That doesn't seem like a good combination.

Answer (score 4):

Is there a reason you can't use `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`? Much easier and impossible to make simple mistakes.

In your case, assuming 32 bit int:

```
int a = 0;   // a = 0
a = ~a;      // a = 0xffffffff = -1 in any twos-comp system
a = -a;      // a = 1
```

So that math is an incorrect way of computer the max. I can't see a formulaic way to compute the max: Just use `numeric_limits` (or `INT_MAX` if you're in a C-only codebase).

Answer (score 1):

Your trick of using '~' to get maximum value works with **unsigned** integers.  As others have pointed out, it doesn't work for **signed** integers.

Your posting shows an `int` which is equivalent to `signed int`.  Try changing the type to `unsigned int` and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

There is **no formula** to compute the max value of a signed integer type in C. You simply must use the `INT_MAX`, etc. macros from `limits.h` and `stdint.h`.

Answer (score 0):

binary `1...1111` would always represent `-1`. Simple math says `-1 * -1 = 1`!
Always remember there's just one zero: `0...0000`. If you'd now swap the MSB and you'd be right, then you'd have `10...0000` which would then be `-0` which can't be true (as `0 = -0` in math, but your binary numbers would be different).

Getting the negative value of a number isn't just about swapping the MSB.

Comment: Wrong. Binary `1...1` represents `-1` only for `signed` integral types.

Comment: Well, right, but in above's example he's actually using `int`- not `unsigned int`.

Comment: Extreme precision in the use of language is required when explaining and illustrating how computers work. This is no soft science in which theories and concepts are allowed to not always work.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite as straightforward as the top-bit indicating the sign. If it were, you could have both +0 and -0. You should read up on two's complement.

The correct answer is

```
max = (~0) >> 1;
```

I'm not a C/C++ expert, so you might need `>>>` instead. You need the shift operator that does NOT do sign extension.

Comment: The problem is that for `signed` types containing negative values the `>>` operator is implementation defined (C++ §5.8 ¶3), in C and C++ you don't have precise control on how the `>>` operator deal with the sign bit. However, you can pass through an `unsigned` type to use `>>` on that one.

Comment: Silly language! ;-) You mean you can't ask it to do a shift without sign extension at all?

Comment: @dty: it's implementation-defined if the sign extension is used or not. But you can always get shift without sign extension using the `unsigned` types.

Comment: So something like (and remember, I'm not a C/C++ guy): `((unsigned int)~0) >> 1` ?

Comment: @dty, that will work fine, yes.  For a sign-magnitude or 2's complement implementation, that is!

Comment: @Carl, @dty: These are the kind of things that C makes difficult, because of the way the standard is worded. Oh, snap, I still remember the days when I said nothing was simpler than 8086 assembly.

Comment: @Eduardo - absolutely. =)  I was an ARM guy for a long time before switching to Intel a year or two ago... I still have my mind blown on a regular basis.

Comment: @dty - C does what the underlying hardware does. Java doesn't bother with that.  :-)

Comment: I come from an ARM background too. Assembler and Pascal, mostly. Very little about C makes any sense to me. Like how the hell you're supposed to write working code in a language that changes how it works from processor to processor! :-)

Comment: @dty: It's pretty easy - you just don't write expressions whose values are implementation-defined unless its for the sake of scaling with the implementation's address space size. Don't use bitwise operators with signed types. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

In 2's complement notation 111111... is -1; now, the unary minus operator does not simply change the sign bit (otherwise it would provide strange results in every normal context), but computes correctly the opposite of the number, i.e. +1.

If you want to change the MSB you could use bitwise operators to simply set it to zero. Notice that however this way of finding the maximum value for the `int` type is not portable, since you're making assumptions about how the number is represented that are not required by the standard.